# A neat C++ standard way to assign maybe zero terminated string from range of chars to std::string

Tags: c++

let's suppose we got a C array that contains **edited:** a sequence of characters (not string), which can be either

1. not 0-terminated

`char string_in_range_1[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'};`

2. or 0-terminated

`char string_in_range_2[3]{'a', 0, 0};`

Is there a brief standard way (like one function call) to assign such a thing to *std::string result* so that *result* will contain 1) "abc", 2) "a", not "a\0\0"?

1)

```
assert(result == "abc");
assert(result.size() == 3);
```

2. 

```
assert(result == "a");
assert(result.size() == 1);
```

like that

```
std::string result;
for (char c : string_in_range_2)
{
    if (!c)
    {
        break;
    }
    result.push_back(c);
}
```

but in one standard function call

Comment: There is no such thing as C array that contains a string that is not zero terminated. C-style strings are zero terminated by definition.

Comment: Only thing you could do is create an empty string and loop with `.back_inserter` as you loop over each character in the character array adding them to the string. Otherwise there isn't any function that does it.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that's not true, there's nothing to stop you having an array of characters without a null terminator

Comment: @AlanBirtles "there's nothing to stop you having an array of characters without a null terminator" There is nothing that makes such thing a "string". The C++ standard only recognises null-terminated strings.

Comment: I think you could say `result.append(array, std::find(array,0)-array)` or such.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI there is neither "C string" nor "C++ string" in question from source side

Comment: @wtom May be n.m wants to emphasize that terminology is important to avoid misunderstandings ;-). In a sentence like "let's suppose we got a C array that contains a string", where "C" and "string" appear in close syntactic and semantic proximity, "string" might plausibly be understood to mean "C string".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica it traverses the buffer 2 times which probably less efficient than having a standard function that tests for 0 and length in each iteration, but still yours is one of the good solutions available

Comment: @wtom Both is true; but there is no standard function because it's not a standard problem ;-) -- this where n.m's remark comes into play, that a non-terminated array simply is not a C string. We have (1) standard functions handling C strings; and (2) standard functions handling arbitrary arrays. What you are asking for is a bastard .

Comment: And the answer Alan linked to is based on the same find() idea.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica ok. i've edited the question even though it's closed as duplicate. thanks =)

Comment: you can use the C-String library function `strlen_s` which exist since C11.  It returns the supplied size if it does not find a null terminator. In the first case it would return 3, in the second case it would return 1. You would pass the size of the array to it via `std::size(array)`

Comment: @Raildex Nice find!

Comment: @Raildex `strnlen_s` is an optional part of C, major compilers do not implement it. `strlen_s` does not exist. `strnlen` is specified by POSIX, is implemented by nearly everyone, and is good enough here (it doesn't check its argument for being a null pointer but this is not important for this application).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica These bastards are everywhere untrusted string input is handled.

Comment: @wtom If you want to be pedantic, my remark also doesn't mention "C string".

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Since we are in pedantic mode ;-): Of course then there **is** "such thing as C array that contains a string that is not zero terminated"! It's just not a C string but a Peter (or, maybe, wtom) String. Re "bastards": In a way, that's a birth defect of the original C string which cannot be safely validated and, therefore, can in effect not be safely handled: You don't know whether the promise of zero termination is kept or not before you find the zero -- or not, which is *very* bad.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That I can write this is proof that a lot of people keep their promises though ;-).